# Microstrip Voltage Boundary Condition

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, microwave, microstrip

I was reading some notes about a microstrip line. Here the scheme with the reference system:

[image]

In this scheme (sorry for the bad quality of the picture) the upper strip is represented as a charge sheet between two different dielectrics (air, with permittivity epsilon0, and the inner dielectric, with permittivity epsilon1).

In these notes there is this boundary condition (together with others):

[image]

Do you know the reason for that? Why the voltage between the strip and GND plane should become 0 if y tends to infinity?

The quantity V(x,y) is defined as a function such that E = -grad (V) (this approximation is true for low frequencies, in which we may assume a TEM propagation mode)

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify what is meant by `V(x,y)`. It's unusual to provide a voltage at a point. There must be something more behind that term.

Comment: I'm sorry, V(x,y) is defined as a function such that E = -grad (V) (this approximation is true for low frequencies, in which we may assume a TEM propagation mode)

Comment: V(x,y) isn't the voltage between the trace and ground, it's the voltage between a point in space and ground. It goes to 0 for large y's because those are points far away from any charges in the system.

Comment: what I don't understand is: if we say that V (x, inf) = 0, it is as if the points at infinite distance from GND were short-circuited with GND.  But in reality It seems strange to me that any point infinitely distant from GND is at 0V